# Tool to compare cluster assignment from different methods

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, partitioning, voronoi

I've got a set of methods that partition a data set into clusters.

For the sake of simplicity imagine 7 samples partitioned into any of 3 clusters for a method. The other method does the same, but the assignment is not necessarily.

I am interested in a tool that plots the different **assignments** in a voroni-like fashion, where the borders indicated the partition a certain sample belongs to (no decision boundaries, no linear transformation of the data - really just the assignments).

I'd like to have a plot similar to the one below:

[image: partition drawing]

Is there any tool that does this?

R would be perfect, but any web site would also be fine.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/compute-and-graph-the-lda-decision-boundary

Comment: No, because I want to compare two different cluster assignments instead of visualizing just one. I'm not interested in decision boundaries at all.

Comment: What are the red and black lines in your drawing?

Comment: Updated to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the visualizations in this article maybe?

> Achtert, E., Goldhofer, S., Kriegel, H. P., Schubert, E., & Zimek, A.
>   Evaluation of clusterings--metrics and visual support.
>   In Data Engineering (ICDE), 2012 IEEE 28th International Conference on (pp. 1285-1288). IEEE.
>
> http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6228189

But I think this does not scale well. It only works for really tiny data sets, you get visual overload too fast.

Voronoi cells *are* 1NN classificator decision boundaries. If this is what you want: just plot two Voronoi cells over each other yourself.

Comment: Link for this: http://www.dbs.informatik.uni-muenchen.de/~zimek/publications/ICDE2012/ICDE12_ELKI_0_5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can try a weighted voronoi diagram. For example with different distance function the polygon cell is different. Most likely the simplest is euclidian distance and manhattan distance. However in weighted voronoi diagram the distance function uses weights.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user538603; In fact its the same what @Anony-Mousse answer is.